# Как проверить массив на наличие элемента? C++

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

есть массив, в него будут добавляться координаты, неважно в каком формате, строкой, например

{"(1,2)", "(2,2)", "(1,0)"}

и надо каждый раз перед добавлением в массив проверять, есть ли уже такой элемент. В с++ новичок, на PHP раньше кодил, там попроще: in_array. В интернете искал, ничего толкового не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста.

ДИСКЛЕЙМЕР: не прошу написать за меня код, просто подскажите, какой функцией, или каким способом.

Так же есть пару других вопросов, если кто может помочь & ответить - напишите пожалуйста в комментариях, свяжемся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это именно массив или, скажем, вектор - надо выполнять поиск. Стандартный алгоритм `find`.

Но можно взять контейнер `set` - в него просто не удастся добавить уже имеющийся в нем элемент.

Comment: Или `std::unordered_set`, если не нужен порядок.

Answer (score 0):

Через стандартный алгоритм `find`

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Point
{
    Point(int _x, int _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
    friend bool operator== ( const Point &n1, const Point &n2);
    int x;
    int y;
};


bool operator== ( const Point &n1, const Point &n2) 
{
    return n1.x == n2.x && n1.y == n2.y; 
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> points {Point(10, 54), Point(43, 54), Point(4, 6)};
    Point toPush(10, 10);
    if (std::find(points.begin(), points.end(), toPush) == points.end())
    {
        points.push_back(toPush);
    }
    toPush = Point(4, 6);
    if (std::find(points.begin(), points.end(), toPush) == points.end())
    {
        points.push_back(toPush);
    }

    for (std::vector<Point>::iterator it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->x << " " << it->y << std::endl;   
    }
}
```

Comment: хорошо, но я раньше пробовал с begin и end - ничего не работало, ошибка неизвестный оператор, или что-то типа того. Хотя подключал все как надо

Comment: вероятно вы не перегрузили его

Comment: сейчас просто слишком мало времени чтоб лезть в point, хочу сделать вс таки через string, ну и  string приходится чаще искать

Comment: Ну смотрите, потом проблем не наберешься =)